# How to detect div and its children using window.onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

Example code:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if(event.target.matches('.myDiv')){
        DO THIS
    }
}
```

Understandably, this only checks if a click is made on `myDiv` specifically.

Without using `<div onclick="function()">` and without hardcoding each of `myDiv`'s children into the if statement, is there a way to check if a click is made on a div and any of its children?

Comment: As in `event.target.matches('.myDiv, .myDiv *')` for descendants or `event.target.matches('.myDiv, .myDiv > *')` for children?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I realised afterwards that I wasn't being very clear. `event.target.matches('.myDiv, .myDiv > *')` is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you should do:

```
var parent_div = document.getElementsByClassName(".myDiv");
parent_div.onclick = function(e) { /*DO SOMETHING*/ };
```

This way you directly check for a click on an element and all of its children instead of getting the click event from `window` and then checking whether it is the element which you want or not.

Comment: Thanks, this would work. In reality, I'm waiting for a click and making sure that it didn't happen within the element. Benjamin's `event.target.matches('.myDiv, .myDiv > *')` works perfectly for what I'm trying to make, but this is a great answer to the question I accidentally made. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('myDiv')) {
               event.target.remove();
         }
 }
```